# Google music: get url to song by name

Tags: .net, google-music

I'm looking for a way, to get url to searching song by name.
For example, I have a song name and I want to get the appropriate url in google music.

It's better to have a something like http request for this.
If it possible...

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Karl Richter , I haven't any code yet, because I investigate this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think thats something you can do sadly, consider the following 2 url's

`https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Various_Artists_100_Clubland?id=B7y4mvvpu2lfxo7jxs4pgju2a6y`

and

`https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Various_Artists_Throwback_Summer_Jamz_Ministry_of?id=Banfqyejdh7jw23az4tfxi5l6ly`

The ID at the end is going to prevent this from creating a uniform approach, and without a catalog of the ID's (assuming they don't change) you would be out of luck. Theoretically you could "sniff" all the potential url's, but that would be alot of work. Google have yet to release a public API for any part of the Play Music side of things.

There do exist some unofficial api's, but nothing that would allow easy catalog searching.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
If there are no any another answers, I will mark this as answered...